# What does \do do?

Tags: tex-core

I saw some code using `\do` and I would like to understand it, which to me means finding out what exactly `\do` does. However, I haven't been able to find it in any sort of reference manual, and it is, quite obviously, ungoogleable. I suspect it's part of basic TeX, but I'm not sure.

What does `\do` do and when would I use it? Where can I find it in the TeX or LaTeX documentation?

Comment: Hard to say without some code. The etoolbox package use it as a scrap macro to format items while looping through a list. If your question refers to something from the core, cure that code and someone will give an answer. As it sits now your question is not clear.

Comment: there's some commentary on this command in *tex by topic* (`texdoc texbytopic`) on p.123.  the code referred to comes direct from `plain.tex`, and there may be more explanation in appendix b of *the texbook* (but i haven't looked).

Comment: see file plain.tex line39

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`\do` is short for `\performsomeactiononanargument` and is typically redefined depending on the `action` that needs to be performed.

For example, consider the `verbatim` environment (or `\verb`). We know that the `verbatim` environment allows you to use certain characters that are otherwise restrictive in their use or application, like `$`, `\`, `~`, `&`, `%`, ... So, in order to set up the environment to treat these characters as *characters* and not their aforementioned special behaviour, `\@verbatim` does (see [`latex.ltx`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co))

```
\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
```

where

```
\def\@makeother#1{\catcode`#112\relax}
\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&%
  \do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~}
```

Therefore, `\dospecials` performs a bunch of category code changes (`\do`'s). It's just a condensed notation that varies depending on the definition of `\do`. It's used in other contexts as well for a similar outcome.

[`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) adopted this usage/notation for "performing some action on an argument" when processing a list of items. For example, when calling

```
\docsvlist{first,second,third,last}
```

`\do` is applied to each of the elements sequentially, as in `\do{first}`, `\do{second}`, `\do{third}` and `\do{last}`. This allows the user to (re)define what the meaning of `\do` is exactly. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \renewcommand{\do}{\item}
  \docsvlist{first,second,third,last}
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{\textbullet~#1 \quad}
\docsvlist{first,second,third,last}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

---

In a very limited context, `\do` is sometimes used to delimit macro arguments. But in that context it makes literal sense, even though a completely different delimiter could have been used. One example of this is used in `\@whilenum` or as part of `\@for` (loop) constructions.

Comment: `! Undefined control sequence.  \performsomeactiononanargument`

Answer (score 26):

It depends on the definition

After

```
 \def\do{hello}
```

then `\do` will expand to `hello`....

In the core latex format it has two unrelated uses.

It is used in "executable lists" in a style derived from plain TeX and described in the TeXBook.

For example `verbatim` internally uses a list defined via

```
\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&%
  \do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~}
```

If `\dospecials` list had been defined as

```
\def\dospecials{,\ ,\\,\{,\},\$,\&%
  ,\#,\^,\_,\%,\~}
```

or

```
\def\dospecials{\ \\\{\}\$\&%
  \#\^\_\%\~}
```

you would need some loop macro to iterate over the list but by having a command separator, all you need to do is define `\do`  locally and then execute the list so `verbatim does

```
  \let\do\@makeother
  \dospecials
```

and `\@makeother` is applied to each of the tokens.

The other use is as a delimited argument. If you *had* needed a looping macro you could have used the form

```
\@tfor\tmp:=\dospecials\do{\expandafter\@makeother\tmp}
```

for the form with no commas, or

```
\@for\tmp:=\dospecials\do{\expandafter\@makeother\tmp}
```

for the form with commas.

here `:=` and `\do` are not actually *defined* to do anything they are just tokens used to delimit the arguments of `\@for` which is defined via

```
\long\def\@for#1:=#2\do#3{%
    ....
```

so the list variable (`#1`) is everything up to `:=` and the list (`#2`) is (after expansion) everything between `:=` and `\do`, with the list body (`#3`) being the next token or brace group after `\do`.

Answer (score 18):

## Place holder macro for lists

`\do` is often used as "place holder" macro in lists. Example is `\dospecials`, which is defined in the LaTeX kernel:

```
\def\dospecials{\do\ \do\\\do\{\do\}\do\$\do\&%
  \do\#\do\^\do\_\do\%\do\~}
```

Here it takes an argument, a letter macro. But the meaning of `\do` does not matter at this time. Then, at the start of the `verbatim` environment, the following can be seen in the code:

```
\let\do\@makeother \dospecials
```

The `\do` becomes a meaning: change the category code of the argument to category `other` (the category for reading verbatim stuff). The list is then executed with this meaning of `\do` as `\@makeother`.

Other examples of the LaTeX kernel are:

- `` \def\verbatim@nolig@list{\do\`\do\<\do\>\do\,\do\'\do\-} `` and the usage:
  `\def\@noligs{\let\do\do@noligs \verbatim@nolig@list}`
- The preamble commands are stored in such a list and deactivated at `\begin{document}`.

## Body macro for loops

Another usage is in loops: `\@whilenum`, `\@whiledim`, `\@whilesw`, `\@for`, `\@tfor`. The `\@while...` macros are followed by some condition and the loop body is available as argument of `\do`:

```
\@whilenum\value{section}<10 \do{Something, \stepcounter{section}}
```

Depending on the evaluation of the condition macro `\do` is redefined to either process the argument or ignore it to end the loop.