# Why does \newcommand{\do}{do} not work?

Tags: macros, renewcommand

I'm trying to define a command `\do` in LaTeX, but for some reason, it does not show up. Why is this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\do}{do} 
\newcommand{\doo}{do} % Dummy command for comparison

\begin{document}
Something prints here: \doo.
But nothing prints here: \do.
\end{document}
```

(If loading packages such as `amsmath`, `\do` is already defined therein, so one needs to `\renewcommand`. Still however, nothing shows when using `\do`).

Comment: don't use it, \do is used a lot in internal code.

Comment: @Miyase I read this, but given this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331484/140772 _do (...) is typically redefined depending on the action that needs to be performed_, I thought that my redefinition of it would also work. Or at least throw some "already defined error", if it's used internally.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok thanks, I'll not then. I was puzzled, since this didn't throw any warning, that it's already used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\do` is used in many places by the kernel or packages as a scratch macro for loops.

If you add

```
\texttt{\meaning\do}
```

after `\begin{document}`, you'll discover that LaTeX prints

```
\noexpand
```

which means that some code executed at begin document has done

```
\let\do\noexpand
```

and that this is the last usage of `\do` in that hook, which holds several settings to be performed just before the document starts. If you load other packages, the meaning of `\do` after `\begin{document}` may be different.

You might think to say

```
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\do}{do}}
```

as the last instruction before `\begin{document}`, but this is not safe either, because code *in* the document might use `\do` at the top level, clobbering your definition.

Use a different name.

See [What does \do do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331483/what-does-do-do) for more information about usages of `\do`.

Comment: Given the use of `\do` in internal code it would be meaningful to define it in the kernel such that `\newcommand{\do}{...}` raises an error.

Comment: @campa Actually, it would have been better *not* using `\do` to begin with, but this is historical and, at the time, it saved tokens.

Answer (score 5):

Your definition does work, but `\do` is redefined during `\begin{document}` so the definition is lost by the time you use it. You can check this using `\show`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\do{do}
\show\do

\begin{document}

\show\do

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

The log tells us

```
> \do=\long macro:
->do.
l.4 \show\do
            
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
)
(./test01.aux)
> \do=\noexpand.
l.8 \show\do
```

that is, `\do` has been redefined to `\noexpand` during `\begin{document}`.

As a takeaway, as the comments mention, `\do` is used internally and you should not rely on its definition not changing.